# Stratified Splitting into Train and Test and Dealing with Few Observations Per Strata

Tags: r, cross-validation

Imagine I have a dataset of soccer players' salaries, nationalities, and heights. I'm interested in seeing whether there is an association between the two variables and the salaries of soccer players. I have come up with a few different models, and would like to compare the models on how well they predict. But to do this, I need train and test data that contain the same levels of nationality in the train and the test data.

So imagine I have data that look like this:

```
> soccer_player_df
     salary nationality   height
1  504731.1         USA 6.466627
2  485333.2         USA 5.468320
3  483259.4         USA 4.694929
4  493594.2         USA 5.685126
5  530805.8     England 5.856093
6  520851.5     England 6.031963
7  484309.9       Spain 6.127087
8  462986.6    Portugal 6.023823
9  492580.1      Brazil 5.949609
10 470410.0      Brazil 5.978207
```

How would I go about splitting the data such that I am guaranteed to have at least one observation of each nationality in the train and test data?

How would I remove a soccer player if he were the only representative of his nationality (and thus for that country, I could not have a train and test pair)?

Comment: See my `stratified` function (for which there's [a `data.frame` version](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112) and [a `data.table` version](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/933ffeaa7a1d718bd10a)). Make use of the `rownames` (or `rn` in "data.table"), and set the sample `size` to `.5`.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comments, I would suggest checking out [my `stratifiedDT` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/933ffeaa7a1d718bd10a) -- with a caveat: you need to be using at least version **V1.9.3** of "data.table", which can be obtained from the ["data.table" GitHub page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/).

I've also used "dplyr" for convenient filtering.

Once you've loaded the function, load the relevant packages and just do:

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
soccer_player_df %>%
  group_by(nationality) %>%
  filter(length(nationality) > 1) %>%
  stratifiedDT("nationality", .5, bothSets = TRUE)
# $SAMP1
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: 
# 
#     salary nationality   height
# 1 492580.1      Brazil 5.949609
# 2 530805.8     England 5.856093
# 3 483259.4         USA 4.694929
# 4 493594.2         USA 5.685126
# 
# $SAMP2
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: 
# 
#     salary nationality   height
# 1 470410.0      Brazil 5.978207
# 2 520851.5     England 6.031963
# 3 504731.1         USA 6.466627
# 4 485333.2         USA 5.468320
```

The `bothSets` is a new argument that lets you return a `list` with the two subsets.

---

If you don't like living on the bleeding edge, you can use [the `data.frame` version of the function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/6424112), which is pretty fast (but not nearly as fast as the "data.table" version).

The usage is pretty much the same:

```
soccer_player_df %>%
  group_by(nationality) %>%
  filter(length(nationality) > 1) %>%
  stratified("nationality", .5, bothSets = TRUE)
```

---

#### Update:

If you just want to use the function and don't want to use "dplyr" just for filtering and piping, you can also do the subsetting directly in the `stratified` or `stratifiedDT` functions. I've added the names of the arguments so that you can see more clearly what is happening:

```
set.seed(1)
stratified(
  soccer_player_df, 
  group = "nationality", 
  size = .5, 
  select = list(
    nationality = names(which(table(soccer_player_df$nationality) > 1))), 
  bothSets = TRUE)
```

Note that there is a `select` argument that lets you specify the subsets you're interested in.